# Rewrite and Redirect with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A client has asked us to replicate all the content from an old domain (bcsbd.com) to their main domain (ywcacam.org), and also create redirects so the old URLs are still functional. Unfortunately, the URLs aren't exact matches, e.g., [olddomain]/about has become [newdomain]/about_soo_bahk_do. There are less than 10 specific URLs to handle, which we initially did successfully using Redirect statements in the old domain's htaccess file:

```
# redirect specific pages to page on new domain
Redirect /about http://www.ywcacam.org/about_soo_bahk_do
```

We also need a catch-all, so that any other requests go to a specific URL on the new domain, e.g., www.bcsbd.com/somefile becomes www.ywcacam.org/soo_bahk_do. We handled this using Rewrite statements:

```
# catch-all for any requests not specified above
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(bcsbd.com|www.bcsbd.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ywcacam.org/soo_bahk_do [L]
```

Quick research showed the Rewrite directives (using mod_rewrite) would always be processed before the Redirect directives (using mod_alias). So we replaced the Redirects with Rewrites:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /about http://www.ywcacam.org/about_soo_bahk_do [L]
RewriteRule /programs http://www.ywcacam.org/programs_soo_bahk_do [L]
...

# catch-all for any requests not specified above
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(bcsbd.com|www.bcsbd.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ywcacam.org/soo_bahk_do [L]
```

The problem is that just the catch-all is working - the new Rewrite rules are being ignored. What are we doing wrong in those statements?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: a front slash does never match in the htaccess. The correct regexp would be `^about$` assuming exact path `domain/about`

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the problem - obviously need to spend more time practicing basic regexp ;-)